# How to resolve error syntax in vendor.js in angular project when i used ng build for deploy

Tags: javascript, angular

I have an angular project and i today deployed it with vs code: `ng-build` command.
I used angular v.8 in my project.
I test speed load page in gtmetrix.com and will minify use js files (vendor.js , script.js , ...).

When i open vendor.js, i looked my file have 100 error as shown:

[image]

How resolved my error in js files?
all error is: `';' expected.ts`

Answer (score 1):

The point of a linter is to help you write code which is consistent and easy to maintain & edit.

The built code is designed to be downloaded quickly. It isn't designed to be easy to maintain. It isn't designed to be edited at all.

Don't run your transpiled code through a linter.